# Ruby post not working

Tags: ruby, http, post

I'm trying to replicate the curl request on [this page](http://habitrpg.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:16466) using Ruby. When I run the curl request from my system it works fine, but Ruby gives me an error. I've tried a few different ways of doing Ruby posts but none of them work. Here's my code:

```
hr_args = { 'type' => 'todo',
  'text' => 'tyy'
}
hr_hd = {"Content-Type"=>"application/json",    
  'x-api-user'=> habit_user,
  'x-api-key' => habit_token
}


url = URI.parse('https://habitrpg.com:443/api/v2/user/tasks')
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.request_uri, hr_hd)
request.body = hr_args.to_json
response = http.request(request)
```

This is the error I get:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `read_nonblock': end of file reached (EOFError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `rbuf_fill'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:144:in `readline'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:39:in `read_status_line'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:28:in `read_new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1408:in `block in transport_request'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1405:in `catch'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1405:in `transport_request'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1378:in `request'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1371:in `block in request'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1369:in `request'
        from todo.rb:38:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use the [Curb](https://rubygems.org/gems/curb) gem? It's a wrapper around libCurl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to set `http.use_ssl = true`.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
...
require 'openssl'
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
...
...
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this doesn't work. I do get this warning though: `warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER`

Comment: I did have to mark `http.use_ssl = true` which your post inspired me to do, so marking this as the correct answer

Comment: Hey @Xodarap, you can leave your own answer to the question and mark it as correct. This particular bit of code disables a key security feature of OpenSSL and it pains me to see it as the "correct" answer.

Comment: @Max it is very interesting to see an accepted answer having a `-1` :-). Has anyone in `SO` would have considered this test scenario?

Comment: It's not so uncommon. The usual case is an answer that the asker found acceptable, but the community believes is incorrect in some way. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255706/why-are-negative-score-accepted-answers-still-at-the-top

Comment: @Max:Thanks for the suggestion, changed the answer